# Change SQL Server primary key using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to change a column type in a SQL Server table.

I need do it using a script or C#.

The original datatype is `integer` and the new type is `varchar(50)`.

I can do it using this SQL script:

```
ALTER TABLE confezionamento ALTER COLUMN partnumber varchar(50)
```

but the problem is that this column is in a set of primary keys.

When I try do execute, an error occurred because `PK_CONFEZIONAMENTO` is using the column.

How I can do it without access to SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: you should remove the c# keywords from this question, as this is sql server related only

Comment: While I very much agree with marc_s, I have worked with many projects where the PK is a string rather than utilizing a UNIQUE constraint on the field (in this case part number) and using an INT PK for foreign keys with much faster queries. These decisions for whatever reason often come down from people who don't understand databases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to run SQL Commands to do the following steps:

- Drop primary key constraint
- Alter primary key
- Add primary key constraint

If there are any foreign keys or indexes, you may have to deal with them as well.

The commands you are looking for will be similar to these:

```
Alter table confezionamento drop constraint PK_CONFEZIONAMENTO
ALTER TABLE confezionamento ALTER COLUMN partnumber varchar(50) 
ALTER TABLE confezionamento ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CONFEZIONAMENTO PRIMARY KEY (partnumber)
```

These commands can all be sent from C# using ADO.Net or similar methods.

Comment: ... and to drop the primary key constraint, you first need to find and drop all referencing foreign key constraints, too.